# Binded model to View but button click on working

Tags: c#, mvvm, icommand

All,
Binded complete Model, values are getting displayed in controls but not able to get button click working... any suggestion? what I m missing or doing wrong ? Thanks

```
<Window x:Class="test" Title="test" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Name="abc" Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding Path=EMP, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="4" Height="153">
        <Label Content="Last Name:" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
        <TextBox Width="250" Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" Height="20"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,4,0" Height="40" Width="40" 
                 Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

class EmployeeVM: ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _Execute = true;
    public EmployeeVM()
    {
        emp = new Model.Employee { FirstName = "abc", LastName = "xyz" };
    }
    private string sFirstName;
    private string sLastName;
    private Model.Employee emp;

    public Model.Employee EMP
    {
        get{return emp;}
        set{emp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EMP");}
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return sLastName; }
        set 
        { 
            sLastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    #region Commands
    private ICommand _SaveCommand;
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _SaveCommand = new CommandHandler(Save, _Execute);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void Save(object param)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Model.Employee> newIM = new ObservableCollection<Model.Employee>();
        foreach(Model.Employee e in newIM)
        {
            string a = e.FirstName;
            string b = e.LastName;
        }
    }
}


public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    Action<object> _act;
    bool _canExecute;

    public CommandHandler(Action<object> act, bool canExecute)
    {
        _act = act;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _act(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you try to achieve?

Comment: @MareInfinitus, I am trying to pass multiple parameters into the CommandParameter which I am not able to do b/c it does not support collection... If u c above.. in case of 1 i/p I am ok... but if i want to pass more then one i/p param to Execute method of ICommand... I am stuck... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `i/p`? This abbreviation is not well known. Best to spell out all of the words and place abbreviations in parenthesis to help those of us who are incapable of understanding "text speak".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own command.

Here is the baseclass I use for my commands.

It has some very basic things that make life easier.

- the `Execute` method accepts an object, so you will be able to pass arrays
- a viewmodel can be easily passed in, that is the one you will work with in your commands (this is most of the time the case, swipe it out if you do not need that)
- the changed handler leverages the CommandManager. This is really very helpful

Perhaps you want to change some things. All I have added is in there because it is very helpful. (especially the viewmodel)

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    public abstract bool CanExecute(object o);
    public abstract void Execute(object o);

    public PropertyChangedBase ViewModel { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

You would have implementations like

```
public class ExampleCommand : CommandBase
{
    public ExampleCommand (PropertyChangedBase viewModel)
    {
        this.ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public override void Execute(object o)
    {
        // something like
        var settings = UnityContainer.Resolve<ISettings>();
        settings.MagicValue = (this.ViewModel as ConcreteViewModel).MagicValue;
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object o)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

in your ViewModel, you expose the command to the view by having a property:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ExampleViewModel ()
    {
        this.DoThisAndThatCommand = new ExampleCommand(this);
    }

    public CommandBase DoThisAndThatCommand { get; set; }
}


// and in XAML, you can use it like
<Button x:Name="Ok"
            Command="{Binding DoThisAndThatCommand }" />
```

(Given you have connected the `ViewModel` and the `View` correctly by setting the `DataContext` of the `View`)

Now, whenever the Button is clicked, the Execute Method of the Command will get called.

You have your ViewModel right in the `Command`, so you can easily work with it.

It is very unusual to have a button inside a command or inside a `ViewModel`.
The trick about MVVM is to separate the `View` from the `ViewModel` and to not have
`UIElements` in the `ViewModel`.

If you do not have the PropertyChangedBase (this one comes with Caliburn.Micro) then I would suggest to use some easy INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

[I found this one here, should be german though](http://dotnet-forum.de/blogs/thearchitect/archive/2012/11/01/die-optimale-implementierung-des-inotifypropertychanged-interfaces.aspx)

public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region < INotifyPropertyChanged > Members

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Is connected to a method which handle changes to a property (located in the WPF Data Binding Engine)
    /// </summary>

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise the [PropertyChanged] event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property</param>

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    #endregion

    private Dictionary<string, object> propertyValueStorage;


    #region Constructor

    public NotifyPropertyChangedBase()
    {
        this.propertyValueStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }


    #endregion



    /// <summary>
    /// Set the value of the property and raise the [PropertyChanged] event
    /// (only if the saved value and the new value are not equal)
    /// </summary>

    /// <typeparam name="T">The property type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="property">The property as a lambda expression</param>
    /// <param name="value">The new value of the property</param>

    protected void SetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property, T value)
    {
        LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = property as LambdaExpression;

        if (lambdaExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid lambda expression", "Lambda expression return value can't be null");
        }

        string propertyName = this.getPropertyName(lambdaExpression);

        T storedValue = this.getValue<T>(propertyName);

        if (!object.Equals(storedValue, value))
        {
            this.propertyValueStorage[propertyName] = value;

            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }


    /// <summary> Get the value of the property </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The property type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="property">The property as a lambda expression</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the given property (or the default value)</returns>
    protected T GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {
        LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = property as LambdaExpression;

        if (lambdaExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid lambda expression", "Lambda expression return value can't be null");
        }

        string propertyName = this.getPropertyName(lambdaExpression);
        return getValue<T>(propertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Try to get the value from the internal dictionary of the given property name
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The property type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property</param>
    /// <returns>Retrieve the value from the internal dictionary</returns>

    private T getValue<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        object value;

        if (propertyValueStorage.TryGetValue(propertyName, out value))
        {
            return (T)value;
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Extract the property name from a lambda expression
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lambdaExpression">The lambda expression with the property</param>
    /// <returns>The extracted property name</returns>
    private string getPropertyName(LambdaExpression lambdaExpression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression;

        if (lambdaExpression.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = lambdaExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            memberExpression = lambdaExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

It is very easy to use!

In your ViewModel you have to provide public properties for Binding **(this is VERY important)** and fire a change notification.

Here is an example of how to use that basic implementation of INPC (INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
public class LoginViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public string UserName { get;set; }
}
```

This INPC implementation makes the NotifyOfPropertyChange call for you, you do not have to care for it! But you will have to inspect what fits your case best.

In your Question you already have a ViewModelBase. Perhaps you want to use this one instead of the above.

Comment: I had to laugh at your summary :D `<param name="o"> The o. </param>`

Comment: have removed them ;) Those were generated of course, I did not write that.

Comment: @MareInfinitus, can you please elaborate more on the implementaion? I mean any sample of your base class? In my code above, I am not able to link the ICommand property to button, missing something.. therefore, on click of button, control not going to .cs file

Comment: @Amit Please have a look at the new example. Have provided more sample code to let you see how it can be used. You do not need any button inside the command as every dataexchange between View and ViewModel is done through `Binding`.

Comment: @MareInfinitus, Thanks once again. only thing I want to achieve is that, want to create a skeleton where normal flow (UI, Middlelayer, DB and vice versa) should work using MVVM.. in my example, as you said, it is unusual to have a command/button inside ViewModel, I tried your implementation too but stuck because could not find unitycontainer and propertychangebase.... As I am new to MVVM, so not able to react immediately .... Only I want to do a normal flow of data and click event using MVVM... Sorry for troubling you but I am still stuck... button click not working... Sorry again..

Comment: You can wipe out the part with unity. You will have to change the PropertyChangedBase to your ViewModelBase. Then it should work. Perhaps you can take parts of the NotifyPropertyChangedBase that I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to write in English, because I was confused what you wrote(such as "If u c above", "b/c", and so on :P..)

Anyway, as for your problem, this should fix it:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <C:MultiValueConverter x:Key="MultiParamConverter"></C:MultiValueConverter>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Name="Expander" Content="+" Width="25" Margin="4,0,4,0" Command="{Binding ExpanderCommand}">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiParamConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="Content"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Expander"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
            <Label FontWeight="Bold">GENERAL INFORMATION</Label>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="Content" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Label>Test</Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Command:

```
public ICommand ExpanderCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(delegate(object param)
                    {
                        var args = (object[])param;
                        var content = (UIElement)args[0];
                        var button = (Button)args[1];
                        content.Visibility = (content.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
                        button.Content = (content.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) ? "-" : "+";
                    });
            }
        }
```

and the converter:

```
public class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values.ToArray();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("No two way conversion, one way binding only.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your view model class should either be a `DependencyObject`, or implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You can always find a suitable MVVM library out there and use their base view model class.

Judging from your XAML that your CheckBox can bind to the same context of your button. So, while you are binding your `buttonGetDetails` into the `ClickCommand` you can also bind your `chkDuplicates` into a view model property, lets say `CheckDuplicates`. Therefore you won't need this as a parameter to your command, because the property will already be inside your view model. Such as:

```
class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    bool checkDuplicates;
    public bool CheckDuplicates
    {
        get { return checkDuplicates; }
        set 
        {
            if(checkDuplicates != value)
            {
                checkDuplicates = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CheckDuplicates");
            }
         }
    }

    //Everything else is same as before
    //  except the action
    public void AnyAction(object param)
    {
        //no need for param anymore
        //var parmValues = (Object)param;
        bool test = this.CheckDuplicates;
    }        
}
```

Since this is supposed to model your view, you can get rid of any parameters of your command binding and make them part of your view model.

Comment: Thanks Zahir, Since I am novice to MVVM so not able to react immediately on what you are saying... need few more thought/code sample... I have 2 control on UI and a button... when user sets some value and click on button.. I need to fill the grid and all this I want to achieve through MVVM.... I appreciate if you could help me with code or link to some code...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I am trying to say is instead of thinking in terms of UI elements like checkbox, listbox etc. we need to think in terms of properties and changes. We just need to shape our view model up, then UI design becomes a bunch of bindings. For base classes you can easily use http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/. If you need some extra sample code just google "MVVM library" or "ViewModelBase".

Comment: Thanks Zahir once again, i did some changes today, was able to bind complete model to UI, values r coming in control, however, when clicking on button, control not going on .cs file (save method)  :(

Comment: Zahir, I have update code above, XAML, ViewModel.. pls let me knw what wrong i am doing or missing something ?  button click not working here... Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you can change the question like that. This looks like a different question now...

Comment: NP Zahir, Thank you and everyone for your comments... I am missing something but not sure what... not able to link button to ICommand property... Need to explore more :)    Thanks all.